# One or two numeric digits Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, digits

I have the below code. It works only when I have 2 digits. If I have 1 digit doesn't work. I want to work in both cases: one or two digit.
`var numberRegex = /^[1-9][0-9]$/;`
I've tried something like this but unfortunately doesn't work:
`var numberRegex = /^[1-9]?[1-9][0-9]$/;`
Thanks for support.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
/^\d{1,2}$/;
```

Reading what you have it looks like you don't want to accept numbers like `01`.

```
/^\d{1}|[1-9]\d{1}$/;
```

Comment: The second regex isn't quite right. `|` has lower precendence than `^` and `$`. You can also simplify by just making the `[1-9]` optional. `/^[1-9]?\d{1}$/`

Comment: Just realized you can do even better - `\d{1}` is redundant, and equivalent to `\d`.

Comment: I'd go with `/^[1-9]?\d$/`  No need for alternation, just make the leading digit optional.

Comment: @MarkReed, your decision is cool but one digit zero is valid for your Regex

Comment: Yes. 0 by itself is valid. That's intentional.

Answer (score 2):

try this regex: `/^[1-9]\d{0,1}$/`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
/^[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]$/
```

This should do the job. Using an Or operator does it.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
/^([0-9]{0,1}([1-9][0-9]){0,2})$/
```