# Swing JTextField - Max 3 digits before decimal and max 2 digits after decimal

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtextfield

Can anyone help me with the validation for `JTextField` which can only allow up to 3 digits before the decimal and up to 2 digits after the decimal?

I used regex `\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}` for `InputVerifier`. This is allowing exactly 3 and 2 before and after decimal. I need `<=3` and `<=2` before and after decimal.

**My project only needs JTextField**.

Comment: Your tag list should include [tag:regex]. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771269/one-or-two-numeric-digits-regex), you can use `\d{1,2,3}.\d{1,2}`.

Comment: Does `^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}$` work for you? It will require at least 1 digit on both sides of the decimal, and the first part can be 1 to 3 digits long, and the second can be 1 to 2 digits long. To allow `.2` like input, try `^\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2}$`.

Comment: *"My project only needs JTextField."*  Why?  In fact, this looks a lot like a case for `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: @stribizhev yes '^\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2}$' is working....

Comment: @AndrewThompson as of now we are asked to use JTextField. So we are trrying to workout with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate such strings, you can use the following regex:

```
^\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2}$
```

It will require at least 1 digit on the right side of the decimal, and the first part can be 0 to 3 digits long (due to `{0,3}` quantifier).

Note that it allows `.2`-like input.

Comment: By using **InputVerifier**, after typing the 4th digit before the decimal and getting the return value from 'verify' method is false. But my query is like, i should not be able to type any digits after entering 3 digits before decimal. Same is the case also with the digits after the decimal. Is there any way for this??????

Comment: You should check the official [InputVerifier documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html). To set up this check, you need to set `tf1.setInputVerifier(new PassVerifier());` to the `JTextField` and inside `PassVerifier`, check `tf.getText()` against the regex. I hope it is clearer now.